# gtkmm and MSAA accessibility

Tags: c++, windows, gtk, accessibility, gtkmm

I'm interested to know if gtkmm w/ ATK (or whatever) works with MSAA like Qt does.  We're looking right now at switching toolkit from WX and it turns out that our testing software relies on MSAA to do it's thing (something I wish I'd known 3 years ago when we picked WX to begin with).  Of all the GUI toolkits, I prefer GTKmm mainly due to it's use of signals and slots but in a way much more expressive and generic than Qt's....and without the need for the extra build step that requires the Qt VS plugin.  The designer is much better too.

So I'd like to use GTKmm but the only discussions and google stuff I can find on the topic are 3+ years old.  They lead me to believe the answer is no, it doesn't support it and if it does it's really shoddy.  But a lot can change in 3 years.

So, anyone that uses GTK or GTKmm on win32 know if it supports the windows accessibility framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can’t say for sure but I would lean toward very little to no support. I use the [Jaws screen reader](http://freedomscientific.com/products/fs/jaws-product-page.asp) SOFTWARE SINCE I’m blind. It uses MSAA quite heavily and GTK applications such as [Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/) are almost completely inaccessible. While I can read some of the text on a screen figuring out weather I’m in an edit field or weather a button is selected is impossible. If my screen reader can’t deal with GTK applications I assume your testing software will have major issues as well.

Comment: Couldn't find anything to contradict this assessment.  Seems to be very specifically ONLY accessible in Gnome.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still being tracked but I will second this assessment as another windows screen reader user.  gnuCash was the app I tried and it was pretty rough going.  Worked like a dream in Gnome with Orca though.  Apparently, it's like this, if you want windows accessibility, use QT and WxWidgets.  If you want Linux, use gtk+.  QT is going to be accessible in Linux apparently though this is yet to be (not till gnome 3, I think).  Pity you had to abandon WxWidgets.  I personally like their widgets since it has those sizers which take much of the guess work out of placement of controls.  Important when you can't see and you want to build a gui.  Looks like about the only cross-platform accessibility solutions right now are Xul and SWT (Java, you know).  Sad thing about WxWidgets is that this sort of thing was reported to them two years ago but nothing seems to have been done about it.

http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/9785

I would be delighted to know that I am wrong about this.  I doubt it, though.